# CSR: Run code once (in OnPostRender) for none CSR stuff, StateInitDone?

Tags: client-side-rendering

I found so little info on **StateInitDone** out there I would like some confirmation.

---

I have code in the CSR `OnPostRender` which creates (non-CSR) DOM elements (easter-eggs) on screen;
I have dealt with all the [MDS](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds) navigation issues using the `asyncDeltaManager` `beginRequest` & `endRequest` functions, they make it so DOM elements are only visible on the one page (DOM elements are **not** removed on MDS navigation)

> letter I : pronounced as 'ei' in the Dutch language meaning 'egg'

That all works with only 3 JSLinks to one **external** (private CDN) JS file (*SharePoint Online can*): https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsQVSR6WOQ8

#### Next problem:

[image]

**Clicking a check-box** fires the `OnPostRender` (ofcourse), which is fine for CSR content,
but I do **not** want my custom stuff to run again.

> Note: Whereas OnLoad the `OnPostRender` fires for **all** WebParts on screen
>
> onclick only the `OnPostRender` for the associated WebPart is executed.

#### The ctx object gives 2 promising named keys:

- **onDataRefreshCompleted** with a whopping (but useless) [one Google result](https://www.google.nl/search?q=onDataRefreshCompleted&as_oq=sharepoint#tbs=qdr:y&q=%22onDataRefreshCompleted%22)
- **StateInitDone** with 500% more (but still useless) [Google search Results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=stateInitDone&tbs=qdr:y&tbo=1&as_oq=sharepoint&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=4vTvVqzHA8b5O-zwmZAF#tbs=qdr:y&q=StateInitDone+sharepoint)

On tracing, `ctx.StateInitDone` seems to be **false** in OnPostRender, also in MDS navigation.

It is **true** once the page has finished (and remains so on checkbox interactions)

So I now have in `OnPostRender` :

```
   if (!ctx.StateInitDone) iCSR.iHunt.hideEggBehind(ctx.view);
```

*the function itself does the check if DOMcontent needs to be added*

#### Questions

- I can't find any Microsoft references;
  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/search/en-US?refinement=145&query=StateInitDone
  what does this value do (more)?
- any other methods to work with non-CSR content?
- just curious...  *onDataRefreshCompleted*  anyone?

> Another SharePoint bug that cropped up, those Checboxes are also
>   displayed for user who do **not** have edit rigths...

Comment: just out of curiosity, what fun stuff are you creating? See lots of questions these days from you on CSR :)

Comment: _When you use a tool for things no-one else uses it for you learn the most..._ https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsQVSR6WOQ8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onDataRefreshCompleted` seems to be a `callback` from what I can see in `INPLVIEW.js`

If you look in the `CLVPRefreshCore` function, its used in the `req.onreadystatechange` ( req is a XMLHttpRequest ) :

```
if (req.readyState == 4 && typeof clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted == 'function') {
            callback = clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted;
            clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted = null;
   }
```

I just a did quick test with the `AJAXRefreshView` function and it was called:

```
g_ctxDict["ctx39"].onDataRefreshCompleted = function() {
    console.log("called");
};

var evt = {
    currentCtx: g_ctxDict["ctx39"],
    csrAjaxRefresh: true
};

AJAXRefreshView(evt, true);
```

---

From what I can find on `StateInitDone` it does not look like it does nothing except from reset some values on the ctx.

In the `CLVPRefreshCore` function from `INPLVIEW.js` under the `onreadystatechange` it does check the `StateInitDone` variable between `OnPreRender` and `PostRender` from the looks of it:

```
if (groupBody != null) {
     ...
    if (groupBody.getAttribute("isLoaded") != null) {
    ...
        if (!clvp.ctx.StateInitDone) ctxInitItemState(clvp.ctx);
```

And the `ctxInitItemState` from `INIT.js`

```
function ctxInitItemState(ctxCur) {
    ctxCur.TotalListItems = 0;
    ctxCur.CurrentSelectedItems = 0;
    ctxCur.LastSelectableRowIdx = 0;
    ctxCur.StateInitDone = true;
}
```

Comment: Cool,that means I can simplify some iCSR code where I did polling. Fun how creating [fun stuff](https://www.youtube.com/embed/7CJ9jJ8dgow) learns you more then any course or project, Anders, if you want my easter egg code, contact me at danny@engelman.nl

Comment: Looks cool @DannyEngelman :)  Btw, you can get the "completed context" in the `onDataRefreshCompleted = function(completedCtx)`